# Identifying symbol in Claude Debussy’s Claire de lune

Tags: notation, sheet-music

[image]

Can someone please let me know what the jagged line connecting the top note to the bottom note is?<sup>1</sup>

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> p. [14](https://archive.org/details/suitebergamasque02debu/page/14)

#### Reference

Debussy, Claude. [*Suite bergamasque.*](https://archive.org/details/suitebergamasque02debu/) Ed. Fromont, E. Paris, 1905.

Comment: Looks like a 8h note ledger spanning two staffs

Comment: The "jaggedness" is an artifact of either reproduction or poor typesetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is a "[beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_(music))."

[image: beam example]

It just looks weird because it's connected over two different staves. They can look this way within one single staff as well (top left):

[image: bean example2]

Comment: ...And it's written over two staves to show it's meant to be played using two separate hands...

Comment: Yes, thanks... I suppose that is noteworthy. I simply answered the 'what' without considering the 'why'  ':-D

Comment: It also works to reinforce the 'togetherness' of the slur in the first bar, in contrast to the LH (merely) being an accompaniment to a phrase starting on the high A-flat in the RH. So the shape of the phrase is up and slooowly down.

Comment: It's not a flag - it's a *beam*. Beams take the place of flags when notating multiple flagged notes as a group.

Comment: It's a beam not a flag.

Comment: Ah yes, touche... edited.